# $uibTooltipProvider doesn't allow specific css property in Angular js

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have used $uibTooltipProvider tooltip in my Angular js App..

I have ten menus horizontally when i hover menus tooltip display bottom of the menu, i want to change only first menu tooltip position, i have written specific css for this

CSS:
sample is a classname.

```
.sample:first-child + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow { 
   border-bottom-color:#000; 
   position: absolute;
}
.sample:first-child + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
   background-color: #000; 
   position: absolute; 
   left: -5px;
   width: 155px !important; 
}
```

This code doesn't work when i am using state appendtoBody:'true'.

$uibTooltipProvider intialized in app.js:

```
.config([
  '$httpProvider', '$uibTooltipProvider',

   function($httpProvider, $uibTooltipProvider) {
   var tooltipOptions = {placement: 'bottom', appendToBody: true};
   $uibTooltipProvider.options(tooltipOptions);
}
]);
```

How to Change first menu tooltip position when i am using appendtoBody:'true' State??????